# autopilot ImportError: No module named input

Tags: application-development

I'm on Ubuntu 13.04. I'm following [this tutorial](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tutorials/quality/how-to-write-autopilot-tests/) to write autopilot tests. I get an error when I try to run or list the autopilot tests:

```
$autopilot list CurrencyConverter

Loading tests from: /home/merlijn/autopilottests/ubuntu-sdk-tutorials/getting-    started/CurrencyConverter/tests/autopilot

Failed to import test module: CurrencyConverter.tests.test_CurrencyConverter Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 252, in _find_tests module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 230, in _get_module_from_name__import__(name)
File "/home/merlijn/autopilottests/ubuntu-sdk-tutorials/getting-started/CurrencyConverter/tests/autopilot/CurrencyConverter/tests/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
from autopilot.input import Mouse, Touch, Pointer
ImportError: No module named input

unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure.CurrencyConverter.tests.test_CurrencyConverter
```

If you need more information, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I had similar problem. Here are my notes resolve:

NOTE: had to get daily update version of autopilot

- This didn’t work by itself: http://unity.ubuntu.com/autopilot/faq/faq.html#q-how-do-i-install-autopilot which just had me run:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install python-autopilot
  ```
- On this page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Testing/Autopilot/ I found different instructions:

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:autopilot/ppa
  sudo apt-get update 
  sudo apt-get install libautopilot-qt python-autopilot
  ```

Then everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of the autopilot devs.

The function you're looking for was introduced in autopilot 1.3. To check your autopilot version, run:

```
dpkg -l python-autopilot
```

If you are running saucy, you will get the very latest version of autopilot every time you do an upgrade. For all other distro released, you will need to add the autopilot PPA, like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:autopilot/ppa
```

If you have any more questions, you might want to join us in `#ubuntu-autopilot`, on irc.freenode.net

Comment: `dpkg -l python-autopilot
` => dpkg-query: no packages found matching python-autopilot